# Access the amount of installs of an app, from that app

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to access the exact amount of installs for an app, from that app ?
I would like to "reward" the first 100 people who download my app.

I could do it myself, using a database that increments everytime someone launches the app for the first time, but I was wondering if something like that already exists, and I didn't find anything so far.

Comment: You can use a third party API like parse

Comment: I totally forgot about Parse, great idea, thanks !

Comment: No problem! :) happy to help always

Comment: There is also Firebase in addition to parse.

Comment: Have you implemented any solution? If so, could you please share the answer (as answer to this question) and select it as accepted?

Comment: I haven't implemented anything yet. But I will share it when it's done, I promise :)

Comment: So. I've been trying to solve it this afternoon, but I'm stuck on the php part. Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723011/cant-retrieve-the-value-of-select-count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done !
I tried Parse but it didn't seem to lead anywhere, so I decided to go for a remote database.

I'm kinda new to PHP and connecting to remote servers, so there may be some mistakes. But so far it gets the job done, **even though sometimes it gets stuck, and there is no way to unstuck it, except by closing the app. I don't know if this comes from an error I made, or if it is because I'm using a cheap and maybe unstable server to test it.** Still, feel free to suggest any improvement you could think about.

Android :

```
@Override
    public boolean isFirst1000() {
        byte[] data;
        HttpPost httppost;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient httpclient;
        InputStream inputStream;

        try {
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://jaimebeaucouplepain.com/first1000.php");

                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                data = new byte[256];

                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int len = 0;
                while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data))) {
                    buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                }

                inputStream.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
        }

        String str = buffer.toString();

        if (str.contains("first1000yes")) {
            return true; // The user is one of the first 1000. We don't have to check again.
        }
        else if (str.contains("first1000no")) {
            return false; // The user is not one of the first 1000. We don't have to check again.
        }
        else {
            return false; // There was an error with the server. We will have to check again (next time the user launches the app for example).
        }
    }
```

PHP :

```
<?php

    require("config.inc.php");

    try {
        $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM first1000");
        $row = $result->fetch();
        $nbUsers = $row["COUNT(*)"];
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response = "Database Error.";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    if ($nbUsers < 1000) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO first1000 (id) VALUES (DEFAULT)";

        try {
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            $response = "Database Error.";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }

        $response = first1000yes;
        echo $nbUsers;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        $response = first1000no;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

?>
```

Here is how it works. Everytime a player launches the app for the first time, we check the database. If there are already 1000 entries, it means the current user is not one of the first 1000 and shouldn't be rewarded. Otherwise, we add an entry and reward the player. Then, we make sure we don't check everytime the player launches the app, because the amount of player will not shrink over time.
We can use a preference like `prefs.putBoolean("checkFirst1000", true)` when it's done.

If there is an error during the process (no Internet for example), we can't reward the player. But we don't call `prefs.putBoolean("checkFirst1000", true)` because we want to check next time, and everytime until we know for sure if the player is or is not one of the first 1000.