# Can't retrieve the value of SELECT COUNT

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm having a very hard time with these 3 little lines of code.
I'm trying to retrieve the amount of rows in a table.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table");
$row = $result->fetch();
$nbUsers = $row[0];

echo 1;
echo $nbUsers;
echo 2;
echo $row;
echo 3;
```

The "echo" part writes "12Array3". It looks like $nbUsers is null or empty, while its value should be 30, since there are currently 30 rows in my table.

count($row) gives 1, which means the array is not empty, so the value I'm trying to retrieve seems to be in that array, hidden.

EDIT :

I also tried

```
$db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) As count from table");
echo 1;
echo $count;
echo 2;
```

But it's the same, it displays "12", $count looks empty.

Comment: Why don't you `var_dump($row);` and see what's really inside it.

Comment: `echo var_dump($row)` writes : array(1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(2) "80" }

Comment: 80 being the value I'm trying to retrieve.

Comment: So you can see that the index of the array was not a `0` but `"COUNT(*)"`

Comment: PHP array can have string as index/key